# Change notifications system in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, notification, notify-osd

I know, there's a similar question on this site, but it's quite outdated.

So I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with standard DE, and the default notifications daemon is a **real pain**. There is even no way to make it switch on sender application window on notification click. How can I change NotifyOSD?